# ComboBox.Item.AddRange(string[]) VS. ComboBox.DataSource = string[]

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, combobox

So, I have two options:

```
aComboBox.Item.AddRange(stringArray);
aComboBox.SelectedItem = stringFromStringArray;
```

and

```
aComboBox.DataSource = stringArray;
aComboBox.SelectedItem = stringFromStringArray;
```

Now, the first one is waaaaay slower when it comes to initialization (about 5-6 times). It does set the selected item properly, but still, it's very slow so I decided to go with the second one.

But, if I use the second one, the Items array within the `aComboBox` is not yet set when the second command is executed, so the selected item is the one at index 1, instead the one specified.

The question is, how do I get the performance of the second one with the functionality of the first one?

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
class MainWindow : Form
{
    string[] list = new string[1548];
    TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel();

    public MainWindow() : base()
    {
        Height = 2000;
        Width = 1000;

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1547; i++)
        {
            list[i] = rand.Next().ToString();
        }

        list[1547] = 5.ToString();

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Press me";
        button.Click += Button_Click;

        panel.Controls.Add(button, 0, 0);

        panel.Height = 2000;
        panel.Width = 1000;

        Controls.Add(panel);

        Show();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
            box.DataSource = list;  //box.Items.AddRange(list);
            box.SelectedItem = 5.ToString();

            panel.Controls.Add(box, 0, i+1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I reproduced the problem with this program. If you change it to `addRange()`, it will take a lot more time, but it will set the item.

Try adding a breakpoint to the `SelectedItem` and then look at the `ComboBox`.
If you set the one, the other will be null (`DataSource` vs. `Items`). The `ComboBox` seems to look into `Items` to check if the string exists within the list, and that's why it fails with `DataSource` method.

Bonus question: Why are all `ComboBoxes` working as one (try changing the value)?

Comment: Can't reproduce second case. Please test it an independent project and post a simple reproduction code.

Comment: Just search through the items until you get the the specified item set the selected index to it

Comment: I tested using 10,100,1000,10000 and 100000 items. It works properly. It sets the `DataSource` first, then it sets selected item.  Probably your `stringFromStringArray` doesn't exists in the array.

Comment: stringFromStringArray exists in the array, it was the first thing I checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is, how do I get the performance of the second one with
>   the functionality of the first one?

If you want it to work properly, you can move the line `box.SelectedItem = 5.ToString();` to the line after adding boxes to panel.

When you use `DataSource` for your combo box, setting `SelectedItem` works only if your combo box exists on your form.

I'm not sure about performance, but sure about functionality.

> Bonus question: Why are all ComboBoxes working as one (try changing
>   the value)?

Because they are bound to the same `DataSource`. In fact they are using a single `BindingManagerBase`.

You can use different `BindingSource` for them. Also you can bind them to `list.ToList()`.

Comment: I'm using a loop to add 36 complex controls to a `TableLayoutPanel` which is in a tab, which is also in a tab, which is in a window. The code would get very messy and ugly if I had to keep the reference to each ComboBox all the way to the window (form). Is there any other way to do it, to make it think it exists before it actually exists? I really don't want to overcomplicate the code and the other way is SO SLOW it hurts...

Comment: I didn't say you should add them to the form, you should set `SelectedItem` after they added to panel. When you add them to panel, they exists on form. But about the performance, I think it's better to let your previous questions receive an answer :)

Comment: Yeah, that for some reason doesn't work in my main program. The problem is that I'm adding everyting AFTER I create it. So the panel that ComboBox goes on? I add it after I put the ComboBox on, in a method that contains the method that deals with the ComboBox. So comboBox doesn't exist until after I'm several methods up the hierarchy. And that panel, it's still nowhere, I have to add it to a tab as well when I'm done creating it. And then that tab to another. And so forth, and so forth. Any ideas?

Comment: **Probably** you can add the panel to form and the make invisible and make your combo boxes work.

Comment: Well that's bullshit. This is some poor control desing if you ask me.

Comment: Yeah, I'll switch back to Java is what I'm gonna do.

Comment: I'll notify you if I had any idea about increasing the performance when loading your combo boxes :) By the way since the post answers your both questions it would be great if you kindly vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: I'll be eternally grateful if you do. Right, as much as I hate it, it is the right answer. I effing hate the way C# deals with GUI. It is so unbearably slow - and that is compared to freaking Java.

Comment: I only put the selected item when creating the ComboBox, and when DropDown is activated, I switch it. That's the solution.

Comment: Yeah, since it only adds one item 36 times instead of 1500 36 times. And each time a ComboBox is opened 1500 items are added to it.

Comment: Happy to hear that it got solved. I was sure it would get solved soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Use teh DataSource method and use the FindString method to find the index of your desired selected text:

```
string[] arrString = {"hello", "how r u", "fine" };
comboBox1.DataSource = arrString;
comboBox1.SelectedIndex=comboBox1.FindString("fine");
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
```

Comment: Won't work because of relationship between `DataSource` and `Item`. It will fail with index aswell.

Comment: What do you mean by the relationship? Use FindStringExact